# Velocity of a mobile point charge at an instant, due to force exerted by another stationary point charge

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics

Consider two point charges of equal charge **Q** and mass **m** seperated by a distance **R** in free vacuum. Both the charges are initially kept stationary despite the repulsive force between them.

After time t = 0, one of the charges is allowed to move while the other charge is still fixed in its original position.

As the mobile charge moves away from the fixed charge, the potential energy of the system **U** decreases and the kinetic energy of the charge **½mv²** (equal to the potential energy lost) increases and the charge gains velocity **v**.

Now the velocity gained by the charge depends on the acceleration which in turn depends on the force it experiences. But this force itself depends on the distance between the charges, which keeps changing due to the fact the charge has velocity pointing radially away.

I want to find the velocity it has at a time instant t after t = 0.

I tried to use conservation of energy and kinematics equations in the differential form (acceleration, force and velocity as functions of displacement, while displacement as function of time), but ended with a second order differential equation whose solution is not a simple function of displacement.

Is there any method more efficient than this?

Comment: > *ended with a second order differential equation whose solution is not a simple function of displacement.* Please include the details of this in the question - what equation you have, what solution you've got.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets go from the beggining.
Force on the charge is determined by Coulomb's Law.

$F=\frac{kQ^{2}}{r^2}$

Now we know
$ F= Ma$

and

$ a= \frac{dx^2}{d^2t}$

substituting this in coulombs law we get:

$ \frac{M dx^2}{d^2 t}=\frac{kQ^2}{x^2}$

now, this is a differential equation that needs to be solved and you can find x w.r.t. t (time) later, by differentiating that you can get v(vlocity) w.r.t. t(time)

the solution is:

$ x= (3kmQ^2 t^2 + c_{1}t + c_{2})^{1/3} $

Differentiating this w.r.t. time:

$ v= \frac{c_{1} + 6 k^2 m^2 Q^2 t}{3 ({c t + 3 k^2 m^2 Q^2 t^2 + c_{2}})^{2/3}} $

In these equations $c_{1} and c_{2}$ depend on initial conditions.

In this specific case, with their starts being from rest, and assuming x=0 at initial position, both $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are zero.

P.S.

My Solution of the deffirential equation is obtained by integrating exppr from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ in reality it should have been integrated from $ R$ to $+\infty$ Sorry for overlooking this in original post.

The general idea and way of solving are correctly stated that still holds true.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).